# Choosing numbers whose divisors can be partitioned into subsets having the equal sum

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, partitions

How can we find the list of natural numbers between 100 to 10000, whose positive divisors can be partitioned into three subsets such that sum of all the elements in three subsets will be equal?

Answer (score 6):

Since the number itself is a divisor the divisors must sum to at least 3 times the number:

```
list = Range[100, 10000];
list = Pick[list, DivisorSigma[1, list] - 3 list // Negative, False]
```

and the divisor sum must be divisible by 3

```
list = Pick[list, Mod[DivisorSigma[1, list], 3], 0]
```

For the remaining integers `LinearProgramming` can attempt to make 3 equal disjoint subsets

```
getPartition = divs  Quiet[LinearProgramming[
     ConstantArray[0, 3 Length[divs]],
     Join[
          NestList[RotateRight, Join[#, #, #] &[UnitVector[Length[divs], 1]], Length[divs] - 1],
          {Join[divs, -divs, 0 divs], Join[0 divs, divs, -divs]}
     ],
     Join[
          ConstantArray[{1, 0}, Length[divs]],
          ConstantArray[{0, 0}, 2]
     ],
     ConstantArray[{0, 1}, 3 Length[divs]],
     ConstantArray[Integers, 3 Length[divs]]]];
```

For numbers between 100 and 10000 a solution is found everytime:

```
ConstantArray[Total[#]/3, {3, 1}] ===
 Partition[getPartition[#], Length[#]].Transpose[{#}] & /@ Divisors[list] // Tally
(* {{True, 169}} *)
```

Comment: So is there some property that guarantees a solution if it satisfies your two constraints? Sure seems like it.